# Establish federation metadata xml file for a RSA Archer webserver as SP

Tags: single-sign-on, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I want to connect to Archer using a Domain Account. I have followed the documentation provided by RSA and populate the field of the Acher Control Pannel. But the ADFS Team asked me to give them the Federation Metadata file for Archer.

I found this ticket ([How to create federation metadata XML for "Relying Party Trust" and "Claims Provider Trusts" for ADFS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064826/how-to-create-federation-metadata-xml-for-relying-party-trust-and-claims-prov)) and tried to use the Federation Utility tools. But I'm asked to select a wcf service ... I don't know which one to use. As anyone an hint on which one to select or on how to make the federation metadata for Archer ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

RSA Archer support Single Sign On for Active Directory accounts out of the box without any magic required as long as your Windows Server you are running IIS on is a part of the Active Directory domain. You just need to enable Single Sign On in Archer Control Panel and allow Windows Forms authentication. You may need to enable it as well in web.config file. RSA has a detailed guide on Archer Support community site about how this can be done.

At this point I have two versions how to interpret your question:

Version 1: I think that the question you want to ask is how to connect Windows Web Server to the existing Windows Active Directory domain.
If this is the case then you need to ask this question in the Windows Administration stack exchange community. RSA Archer product has nothing to do with making Windows server trust each other on Active Directory domains.

Version 2: You probably are trying to expose Archer to the external users, so the domain you are trying to establish "federation" with is not the same as your Windows Server domain. In this case your question would make sense.
And in this case I would ask your team to provide you detailed instructions about how to extract required information. Different federation services/products may require different information.
In my past experience I asked to have a call with a federation service administrator and followed his instructions and gathered the info he wanted.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Stan for your answer, it shed a new light on my problem. If I understand well what you said, I only need to input the parameters of the federation in the Archer Pannel and then *connect* the web server to the AD domain? But if I can connect on the web server with my domain account, doesn't it mean that the server is already part of the AD domain?